Translating the "Targum" in Dirshu Mishna Berura
The Targum on Dirshu Mishna Berura (454:13) translates גרויפי"ן as גריסים (beans) and רעצק"ע as כסמת טחונה דק (ground spelt). Those translations don't seem to make sense in the context of this Mishna Berura (below): "If soldiers force Yidden to make גריסים (beans) for them on Pesach, then ideally try to appease them with כסמת טחונה דק (finely ground spelt)."

 כתב הח"א כשאנשי חיילות עוברין בפסח וכופין לישראל לבשל להם מיני
גרויפי"ן אם יכול לפייסן שיבשל להם של רעצק"ע מה טוב ועכ"פ יברר אותם
מגרעיני תבואה שמצוי בם ואם אינו יכול לפייסן בזה ונותנין לו גרויפין של
שעורים אם יכול להציל עצמו בממון מחויב ליתן כפי יכלתו ואם לאו אזי יזהר
הישראל עכ"פ לעשות חליטה דהיינו שיניח לבשל המים מקודם עד שיהיה מבושל
הרבה ואז יניח הגרויפין מעט מעט כדי שלא יתקרר המים וגם ברעצקי טוב שיעשה
כן אבל גרויפין של שבולת שועל הוא חמץ גמור כידוע עכ"ל

Moreover, the Mishna Berura (208:23) clearly defines גרויפין as one of the chameshes minei dagan and רעצק"ע as a food that is not one of them, which fits perfectly in the earlier Mishna Berura: "if soldiers are forcing Yidden to make גרויפין (chametz), try to appease them with רעצק"ע (not chametz)."

 שהכל - דכיון שהמים רבים עליו כ"כ עד שאינו ראוי לאכילה ורק לשתיה אינו
בכלל מאכל כלל ומברכין שהכל כברכת המים. וכ"ז הוא דוקא בקמח שממשו אינו
בעין ומתבטל בריבוי המים אבל העושה תבשיל ממיני גרויפי"ן שנעשה מה' מיני
דגן [כגון הנעשים במדינתנו משעורים ושבולת שועל שנחלק כל גרעין לשנים]
ונתן בהם מים הרבה עד שאינו ראוי רק לשרפו שקורין זופ"א אין הגרויפ"ן
בטילין לגבי המים כיון שהם בעין ומיני דגן לא בטלי וצריך לברך על
הגרויפי"ן במ"מ ומ"מ אפשר שגם המים לא בטלי לגבייהו כיון שעיקרן נעשה רק
לשתיה ולא לאכילה וצריך לברך גם על המים שהכל וע"כ יברך תחלה על המים
ואח"כ על הגרויפי"ן [כן מתבאר מדברי המ"א בסימן זה ובסימן ר"ה] ובח"א כתב
שיותר טוב בזה לברך שהכל על דבר אחר ויוציא את הרוטב. וכ"ז דוקא בה' מיני
דגן דלא בטלי אבל בשאר מינים כגון רעצק"ע גרויפי"ן שנעשים בריבוי מים
שאינם ראוין לאכילה ורק לזופ"א מברך ברכה אחת שהכל
דהגרויפי"ן נתבטלו לגבי המים

Am I missing something with this Targum or perhaps should their definitions be switched?

כוסמת in modern Hebrew does mean buckwheat, not spelt (which is כוסמין).

In Modern Hebrew, speakers of which are the primary audience for Dirshu's translations, גריסים usually connotates barley corns. If you ask for גריסים in an Israeli supermarket, that's what you're going to get. And כוסמת means buckwheat, not spelt (which is called כוסמין in Modern Hebrew).
Therefore, it makes perfect sense. If they are being forced to make גריסים (i.e. barley, which is machmitz), they should try to get away with making כוסמת (i.e. buckwheat, which is not machmitz).

The word גרױפּן is Yiddish for grains, and רעטשקע is Yiddish for buckwheat (both confirmed by the Comprehensive Yoddish-English Dictionary). Buckwheat is notably not actually a grain, despite the name. Thus, your intuition as to what it should mean is correct, and I can't account for the Dirshu translation.
